# Ruby Book For exprienced programmers with exercises

Tags: ruby

I am looking for a good ruby book for experienced programmers (I have been developing in C# and Java for the last 7 years) and i am finding it difficult.

Either the books are directly oriented for beginners or they provide just a brief overview of the language for experienced programmers.

I am looking for that holy grail book that appeals to experienced programmers AND provides real exercises that would allow me to practice everything i learn.

My expectations from this book is to be able to finish it and start learning rails while developing my own web application.

Thanks in advance for any help provided,
Dan

Comment: Just to clarify, you're looking for a rails book, not a ruby book, correct?

Comment: Actually a ruby book, I think the rails topic is covered well in the Michael Hartl website that can be found here: http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book

Comment: why all the good questions are closed on stack overflow ? why ? :|

Answer (score 2):

Take a look on this:
http://ruby-metaprogramming.rubylearning.com/

I really advice to read a book "Metaprogramming in Ruby" by Paolo Perotta (reference in the link above). Also you can do some Ruby Koans :)

Comment: +1 Perotta's book is my favorite. It is interesting and make you a ruby guru like the title says. btw, the name of the book is without `in`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest taking the [coursera SaaS class](https://www.coursera.org/course/saas) (site seems to be down right now, probably as a Sandy precaution) - it's free and covers quite a lot of stuff (Rails, Cucumber, Heroku, ...), including exercises that are automatically checked and graded.

Comment: Thanks Frank, though i couldnt access the link you provided...

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer, the site seems to be down right now - probably as a Sandy precaution).

Comment: must have missed that :) Thanks Frank!